# How to pass %CD% to an app using GuiMacro Shell in ConEmu

Tags: conemu

The [documentation on Shell](http://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html#Shell) isn't very clear, perhaps I am getting confused.

1. How can I pass %CD% as an argument to a command I am running?
2. What exactly is the first argument? What does '"open", "print" so on' mean? What is "","" in the second example mean.

In particular, I am interested in running a command like so:

```
Shell("open","explorer","%CD%")
```

But that doesn't quite work. `explorer` opens, but not with the CD. The very last example of the documentation does work:

```
Shell("new_console:Ibn","cmd","/k start explorer \"%CD%\" && exit")
```

This is puzzling. Why is this working and not the other?

I am using build 161022 (latest as of writing).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Shell` macro has much in common with [ShellExecute WinAPI function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx). So `open`, `print` and others has same meaning as `lpOperation` argument of the function.

Alternatively, the first Shell's agrument accepts ConEmu internal [new_console switches](http://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html), without leading dash.

Next, ConEmu does not expand variable names to their values when execute `Shell` function. You can easily check this with [Process Explorer](http://conemu.github.io/en/ProcessExplorer.html) by executing `cmd` instead of `explorer`. Example:

```
Shell("open","cmd","%CD%")
```

When you run `Shell("open",...)` ConEmu does not do environment inheriting. But when you specify `new_console:I` instead of `open`, it does. So in the example from the site `CD` is "inherited" properly.

At last, you have not quoted `%CD%` properly in your first example. That actually does not matter (it would not work either), but correct notation would be `..., "\"%CD%\"")`, same as in the example from the site.

Comment: This is very revealing, thanks. So, how to pass CD to an app without creating a new tab and new console? (Even though it is in the background, kind of indirect and slow)

Comment: hey maximus, is there an active forum for ConEmu?